# Batch processing in Linux?

Tags: linux, batch, bash-scripting

What kind of script I need to run a batch on Linux?

I have to launch this line

```
php magmi.cli.php -profile=FINALE -mode=create -CSV:filename="path/to/file01.csv"
```

40 times for 40 different CSV files unless I have a script to exectute them all in a batch style.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple shell script. To run your command 40 times, do:

```
for file in path/to/*.csv; do 
      php magmi.cli.php -profile=FINALE -mode=create -CSV:filename="$file";
done
```

The construct `for VARIABLE in PATH; do SOMETHING; done` goes through every file (or and folder) sequentially, assigning `VARIABLE` to each file/folder name in turn. It then runs whatever `SOMETHING` is once for each file. You can then refer to the file using `$VARIABLE`, for example, in the script above, `VARIABLE` is `file` and I pass it to `php` as `$file`.

Comment: and I guess save this as .sh file right?

Comment: @GabrieleCripezzi The extension is irrelevant. You tell the OS it's a `sh` script by either running it as `sh yourscript` or by adding a `#!/bin/sh` line at the top of the file... Alternatively, just paste the whole command into the terminal.

Comment: @GabrieleCripezzi you just open a terminal, copy paste the command and hit enter.

Comment: ok it's done. created a import.sh file into /scripts and executed (no #!/bin/sh att he beginning of he file because vim didn't allow me to.
I chose the file solution vs the ssh cli as it seems more reliable in case of loss of internet connection here.
By the way... is it safe to shut thePC down now that the batch has been launched or do I have to keep it on?

Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: @GabrieleCripezzi its safe, it wont harm your machine but it will stop the process obviously.

Comment: No... I am in remote, using Putty to control my dedicated server. I can shut my PC down right? The process will keep running on the server?

Comment: @GabrieleCripezzi probably not actually, it depends. The best thing to do is to run it again using [`nohup`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html). Just stop it (Control+C) and then launch as `nohup import.sh`

Comment: It looks like thee's not need to use nohup. Thanks a lot guys